# LayoutParams are not applied for children within ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using LinearLayout inside a class extending ScrollView. LinearLayout has number of children the height of which changes within overriden onScrollChanged() method of my custom class. Everything works perfect if scrolling is performed slowly. If I make a fast scroll with the fling movement the height of children frizzes. I have made log output in overridden onScrollChange() method and it shows that layout params are not applied.

```
Log.v("myapp", "getHeight: "+mChildHolder.getChildAt(i).getHeight());
Log.v("myapp", "getLayoutParams.height "+mChildHolder.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height);
```

The output:

```
getHeight: 45
getLayoutParams.height 90
```

Any ideas why the scrollview doesn't allow to apply LayoutParams after fling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like solution is found. I ended up calling requestLayout() on every call of onScrollChanged(). Not sure whether it is efficient in terms of performance but it now works as expected.